# SSIS Script Task connecting to AD

Tags: ssis, active-directory

I have written a SSIS 2005 script task that connects to Active Directory and reads user accountnames to store in database.  I was able to successfully test this on my local system by executing dtexec.exe cmd.  However, when I try the same on the server, the ldap query times out.  The same ldap query as a console application just works fine.

I'm using .NET class: System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection and SendRequest to retrieve user account names.

Could you let me know if I'm missing something?

Thanks!

=========

Update:  I'm actually getting "Ldap Server is unavailable" error.  Still not sure, what might be causing this error.

Answer (score 0):

Check the credentials that you are using in server to get the data from ADS. It should be a domain account I think. This will be different from what you used at development environment. Plus check if the DNS/WINS names you use is correctly getting resoled to IP address.